# Android: Gmail Intent Filter Text Plain

Tags: android

I use gmail to choose my app for selected data.I hope that the text "abcdefg" can be return to gmail as text.

```
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "abcdefg");
            ((Activity) context).setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, shareIntent);
            ((Activity) context).finish();
```

this is xml

```
     <activity
        android:name=".IntentFilter2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_intent_filter2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

There is no any error appearing. "abcdefg" cannot be return to gmail. It load a second but return nothing. Why? And what can i do to return the "abcdefg" to gmail as text? Please Help!!

Comment: What did you mean by "**cannot be return to gmail**"?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to open Gmail application from your application to send the plain text. You simply need to launch new Activity with the ACTION_SEND as shown below:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

This will open an application chooser dialogue. You can choose Gmail to open it in Gmail application. The calling Activity, which is IntentFilter2 in your case do not need any intent-filter to do this.

Comment: Actually, i want to use Gmail to open my application and my application return the text to Gamil. Thanks btw.

Comment: You cannot control Gmail application to do that. you are intending to do something which is not feasible.

Comment: Gmail can choose my application to get the photo to share but text cannot be got?

Comment: the photo can generate as a uri, and share it as a file.

Comment: When you click 'Attach file' in Gmail, it invokes ACTION_GET_CONTENT, Your application can provide a file which will be attached to that email. I don't think we can return plain-text to Gmail this way.

Comment: It cannot be return? There is no any error message appearing. I thought my coding having problems. However, why it can be chosen? It invokes ACTION_GET_CONTENT but my mimeType is text/plain.